# Switching contentTypeId while fetching data from Contentful

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, contentful, contentful-api

I'm trying to display some FAQs content in my app using contentful, below is my UserFAQs.swift class which I'm using to fetch the data and this works fine. Now I have a new requirement for adding FAQs for guest user. Only the data is different per user all other things are the same. So, I created a duplicate content model of my existing **userFAQs** called **guestFAQs** and added the content for it. In my below class here they both work individually for eg: if I set contentTypeId = “guestFAQs” or contentTypeId = "userFAQs" in my below class it works fine. But I need to fetch based on the user type and when I set the contentTypeId based on the condition below it always gives me the result as **"userFAQs"** even when the userType is guest. Am I missing something here? Any help is appreciated. 
[This](https://github.com/contentful/contentful.swift) is the library that I'm using.

```
import UIKit
import Contentful

final class UserFAQs: EntryDecodable, FieldKeysQueryable, Resource {

    static var contentTypeId = (Utilities.userType == .normalUser) ? "userFAQs" : "guestFAQs"

    let sys: Sys
    var sectionIndex: Int?
    var sectionName: String?
    var questionName: String?
    var answer: String?

    // MARK: Initialization
    public required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        print("APIName = \(UserFAQs.contentTypeId)")
        sys         = try decoder.sys()
        let fields      = try decoder.contentfulFieldsContainer(keyedBy: UserFAQs.FieldKeys.self)

        sectionIndex       = try fields.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .sectionIndex)
        sectionName      = try fields.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .sectionTitle)
        questionName       = try fields.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .questionName)
        answer    = try fields.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .sectionText)
    }

    enum FieldKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case sectionIndex, sectionTitle, questionName, sectionText
    }
}
```

Comment: Without more information regarding the implementation of `Utilities.userType` one can only provide a speculative solution. However, you probably shouldn't be declaring `contentTypeId` as a `static var`. Swift implements `static` as a lazily initialized one-time value, where the `var` decl means it may be reassigned in the future. Hence, after the first point of use `contentTypeId` will always be the initial value unless you change it at some other point. Perhaps `Utilities.userType` is `.normalUser` when first called.

Comment: Here the contentTypeId is a part of protocol of EntryDecodable given as part of the Contentful library, so we can't change its type.

Comment: then create a another static variable (e.g, _contentTypeId) with an optional String type. Use that as backing for contentTypeId, then for it’s getter return the appropriate user-based ID if the backing variable is nil. The setter should set the backing variable directly. Let me know if you need an example of what this would look like.

Comment: Can't you make two functions `getUserFAQs`and `getGuestFAQs` and set each of them up with the according contentTypeId? And then depending on your user type you call either the one or the other function?